# Como deletar (vários) branches de um repositório Git?

Tags: git, branch

Quero fazer um fork de um repositório que tem dezenas de branches, mas vou utilizar apenas 2 branches.

Queria saber Uma maneira simples de excluir todos os branches que não vou usar, pois estive tentando deletar eles mas não consegui.

Sei que o histórico de commits é importante e que eu poderia simplesmente usar um fork do projeto inteiro, mas acontece que são realmente muitos branches e a maioria dos commits nos outros branches não tem nada a ver com os que utilizarei, ou seja o histórico de commits desses não me interessa e não afeta os branches em que vou trabalhar de maneira alguma.

Além disso, esse projeto por algum motivo não tem um master branch, portanto, os histórico de commits são bem diferentes em cada branch.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode criar um Branch principal(era para ser o Master, mas tudo bem), da um merge pedindo para especificar os conflitos.

```
git merge --no-ff nome-branch
```

E depois você pode fazer isso aqui:

```
git branch -D 3.2 3.2.1 3.2.2
```

Basicamente, git branch irá deletar múltiplos branch para você com uma única invocação. Infelizmente não faz a conclusão do nome da agência. Embora, no bash, você possa fazer:

```
git branch -D `git branch | grep -E '^3\.2\..*'`
```

Comment: No caso desse `3.2 3.2.1 3.2.2`, o que isso significa exatamente (para eu poder entender o que está acontecendo nesse comando)

Comment: Além disso ( e para ser mais específico), estive pensando aqui agora há pouco e o ideal seria que eu tivesse um master branch (algumas mudanças irão afetar todo o projeto) e os 2 branches específicos nos quais eu irei trabalhar. Cada um tem suas particularidades mas existem várias mudanças que serão comuns à amboa, e utilizando a atual estrutura do projeto eu teria problemas se não tivesse um master branch.

Comment: Estou especificando os Branchs que quero apagar, você tem que informar o nome do Branch que quer apagar. Nesse comando estou falando que quero apagar (local) os Branchs (3.2, 3.2.1, 32.2).

Comment: Por isso informei que você deveria ter um Branch Principal(Master).